# Where can I find the Stack Overflow Markdown editor?

Tags: discussion, markdown, editor, javascript

Where can I find / download the source code that is used for the Markdown editor used by Stack Overflow? This is what it looks like:

> [image]

Comment: @Neal: Why would this belong on meta? It's (a poorly crafted question) about software/code, not about Stack Overflow itself. Am I mistaken?

Comment: @Wesley fair point! Anyway, it's on Meta now, it can be (and is already) answered well here.

Comment: You know, based on the screenshot, I don't think this is actually asking about Markdown at all. The OP seems to want the source code for the post editor, and has just gotten the terms confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [MarkdownSharp](https://github.com/StackExchange/MarkdownSharp) on GitHub.

Comment: Can you/anybody tell me where is the documentation of the `MarkdownSharp` ?